# Unity isn't properly rendering 2D sprites

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, sprite

So for some reason my 2D sprites are rendering in a worng way.
In the scene it's ok, but not in the actual game.

What I tried:

**Filtering mode: Point(no filter)**

**Tried different Max Size options**

**Tried different Pixels Per Unit options**

Nothing seems to help, the sprites keep appearing in that strange way, any suggestions?

StackOverflow doesn't allow me to add images to my posts so there they are on imgur.

Scene view: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJ6jO.jpg (proper way)

Game view: https://i.stack.imgur.com/efimm.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The problem might not actually exist but is probably due to Unity rendering the game in a low resolution to fit it in the game view. Try zooming in by making a high custom resolution for the game view (e.g. 1920x1080) and then zooming in or by lowering the orthographic size of the camera and see if the problem still persists.